# Image Picker in PopOverController with Custom NavBar Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am working on iPad app. I want when image picker is open it opens from Library pictures. Image picker should able user to select multiple files. I am really stuck with this one.

[image]

[image]

I have made like this. but bad nav bar and no multiple selection.

Comment: don't dismiss the popover when the image is selected, dismiss it on the done button and keep the ref of images in an array, that might work